# How to tell mongodb aggregation framework to execute on primary node

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Mongodb replica set with 3 nodes and a Spring app configured like this:

```
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="${mongo.replicaset}">
            <mongo:options auto-connect-retry="true" slave-ok="true" />
    </mongo:mongo>
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.dbname}" username="${mongo.username}" password="${mongo.password}" mongo-ref="mongo" />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
     </bean>
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.nounou.repository" />
```

When I run an aggregation operation using mongoOperations it goes to a secondary replica.
And because I'm trying to write the result directly into a connection using the `$out` stage, I get this error:

```
"errmsg" : "failed to create temporary $out collection 'smn.tmp.agg_out.410': { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"Not primary while creating collection smn.tmp.agg_out.410\", code: 10107, codeName: \"NotMaster\" }"
```

Basically, it says that it can't write the results to a secondary node.
If I set  `slave-ok="false"`, I don't get the issue anymore because it switchs the read operations also to the primary node.
But I can't consider this a solution because it will make only 1 node managing the reads and writes.

Is there any configuration or workaround (on spring or mongodb levels) to force teh aggegations to be processed on the primary?

Comment: Something is not right here. Show the related entries from your properties file as I suspect that you're actually simply connecting to the secondary node and not really the "replica set" as it were. The `slave-ok` is the main indicator that this is the case as it should be totally unnecessary otherwise.

Comment: mongo.replicaset=host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3

Comment: Yep. Missing the `?replicaSet=name` option. That's just connecting to the "first contactable host" without it, and it's likely `host1` is a "secondary" in your list. That is really just meant to be the "seed list" of "hosts to attempt connection". It's the actual `replicaSet` parameter which determines you actually connect to a replica set. It's also "preffered" to use the URI option. Furthermore you should have read preference settings on "at least" the database selection, and with this misconfiguration it's likely not there at all.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example using URI with the correct parameters?

Comment: Looking right now. The [spring mongo docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) are a little misleading since they omit the option as well, and I'm yet to see anything in the way of answers that do much more than reference the documentation. The [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) has various examples. But trying to put together something more complete or see if I have something readily available.

Comment: @NeilLunn adding ?replicaSet=name didn't fix the issue

Comment: After changing to URI option it now works correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think some concepts are needed here:

1. If what you want is to distribute capacity for read and write operations across a group of machines, then you need to implement [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) and not a replica set.
2. Do not use secondary and secondaryPreferred to provide extra capacity for reads, because all members of a replica have roughly equivalent write traffic; as a result, secondaries will service reads at roughly the same rate as the primary.
3. You cannot write on a secondary node in a replica set.

You can find all this information [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/)